# Can the Unix list command 'ls' output numerical chmod permissions?

Tags: unix, command-line, permissions

Is it possible when listing a directory to view numerical Unix permissions such as `644`, rather than the symbolic output `-rw-rw-r--` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 420, accepted):

it almost can ..

```
 ls -l | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
             *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}'
```

Comment: For creating it as an alias (example below: 'cls' command), use:

 ```alias cls="ls -l | awk   '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(\"%0o \",k);print}'"```

Comment: I copy and pasted the line from danger89 and found that strangely the output began with %0..o per line, instead of say 755. If anyone else comes across this, the cause appears to be a hidden character between the 0 and o. Once deleted the command is set up nicely. Cheers!

Comment: I think there is an calculation issue. After `chmod 777 dir` your command prints permissions as `767`

Comment: As Donna mentions, there is a funny character (or 2) between the 0 and o, also, weirdly it looks like SO is adding it...

Comment: Does anyone have a working alias for this command? awk runtime error involving "%0o " on a debian derivative

Comment: This fails to recognize bits t and s.  You should use the 'stat' command to get the file permission information.   Calculating it by hand will lead to errors!

Comment: @danger89 `awk` actually preserves the color if you use the `ls` option `--color`, too.

Comment: Nice but doesnt work in www.codeanywhere.com virtual machine terminal.

awk: cmd. line:3:
awk: cmd. line:3: ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:3:              *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}
awk: cmd. line:3:                       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:              *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}
awk: cmd. line:3:                             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:              *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}
awk: cmd. line:3:                                             ^ syntax error

Comment: I wanted the 4 digit codes to give chmod to replicate. `ls -l|awk '{if($1~/^.{10}[.]$/){k=0;for(i=0;i<9;i++){c=substr($1,10-i,1);if(!(i%3)){k+=(c~/[stST]/)*2^((i/3)+9)};k+=(c~/[r-x]/)*2^i};printf("%04o ",k)};print}'`

Answer (score 204):

Closest I can think of (keeping it simple enough) is `stat`, assuming you know which files you're looking for.  If you don't, `*` can find most of them:

```
/usr/bin$ stat -c '%a %n' *
755 [
755 a2p
755 a2ps
755 aclocal
...
```

It handles sticky, suid and company out of the box:

```
$ stat -c '%a %n' /tmp /usr/bin/sudo
1777 /tmp
4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: This works great under Linux, I found `stat -f '%A %N' *` does the same thing on a mac (FreeBSD)

Comment: I guess the argument is that `stat` is not `ls` therefore this is not the correct answer. However, I believe this is the correct answer in context of the desired output. If `awk` is permitted in a pipe, then `find` should be permitted where `stat` is called in `-exec`; then you can use `stat` directly without `*`

Comment: This is much better shorter and 100% working on any system

Comment: If you want to use stat to see the rights recursively, under bash, use `stat -c '%a %n' * **/*`.

Comment: according to `man stat -c or --format`: `%a access rights in octal (note '#' and '0' printf flags), %n file`

Answer (score 80):

you can just use GNU find.

```
find . -printf "%m:%f\n"
```

Comment: This is a command I can actually remember. Helpful and effective.

Comment: This should also have `-maxdepth 1` option, otherwise it traverses the whole directory tree.

Answer (score 53):

You can use the following command

```
stat -c "%a %n" *
```

Also you can use any `filename` or `directoryname` instead of `*` to get a specific result.

On Mac, you can use

```
stat -f '%A %N' *
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. `stat: illegal option -- c`
`usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`

Comment: works on ubuntu 14.04.. to never have to remember this I've added an alias in my .bashrc: alias xxx="stat -c '%a %n' *"

Comment: Helpful! How you dig it out the %A which not even shows up in man of stat on Mac?

Comment: It actually is a FreeBSD command, and Mac just happens to be built upon that using it as upper kernel.

Comment: If we only use the information presented in `man stat` on macOS 10.14.4, then the command should be `stat -f "%Lp %N" *`. `%Lp` appears to print the same thing as `%A`.

Answer (score 24):

Use this to display the Unix numerical permission values (octal values) and file name.

```
stat -c '%a %n' *
```

Use this to display the Unix numerical permission values (octal values) and the folder's sgid and sticky bit, user name of the owner, group name, total size in bytes and file name.

```
stat -c '%a %A %U %G %s %n' *
```

[image]

Add `%y` if you need time of last modification in human-readable format. For more options see [stat](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stat.1.html).

**Better version using an Alias**

Using an alias is a more efficient way to accomplish what you need and it also includes color. The following displays your results organized by group directories first, display in color, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G) edit your `~/.bashrc` and add an alias for your account or globally by editing `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh`

Typing **`cls`** displays your new LS command results.

```
alias cls="ls -lha --color=always -F --group-directories-first |awk '{k=0;s=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++){;k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwxst]/)*2^(8-i));};j=4;for(i=4;i<=10;i+=3){;s+=((substr(\$1,i,1)~/[stST]/)*j);j/=2;};if(k){;printf(\"%0o%0o \",s,k);};print;}'"
```

[image: Alias is the most efficient solution]

**Folder Tree**

While you are editing your bashrc or custom.sh include the following alias to see a graphical representation where typing **`lstree`** will display your current folder tree structure

```
alias lstree="ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'"
```

It would display:

```
   |-scripts
   |--mod_cache_disk
   |--mod_cache_d
   |---logs
   |-run_win
   |-scripts.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 19):

@The MYYN

wow, nice awk! But what about suid, sgid and sticky bit?

You have to extend your filter with s and t, otherwise they will not count and you get the wrong result. To calculate the octal number for this special flags, the procedure is the same but the index is at 4 7 and 10. the possible flags for files with execute bit set are `---s--s--t` amd for files with no execute bit set are `---S--S--T`

```
ls -l | awk '{
    k = 0
    s = 0
    for( i = 0; i <= 8; i++ )
    {
        k += ( ( substr( $1, i+2, 1 ) ~ /[rwxst]/ ) * 2 ^( 8 - i ) )
    }
    j = 4 
    for( i = 4; i <= 10; i += 3 )
    {
        s += ( ( substr( $1, i, 1 ) ~ /[stST]/ ) * j )
        j/=2
    }
    if ( k )
    {
        printf( "%0o%0o ", s, k )
    }
    print
}'
```

For test:

```
touch blah
chmod 7444 blah
```

will result in:

```
7444 -r-Sr-Sr-T 1 cheko cheko   0 2009-12-05 01:03 blah
```

and

```
touch blah
chmod 7555 blah
```

will give:

```
7555 -r-sr-sr-t 1 cheko cheko   0 2009-12-05 01:03 blah
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I shortened it to a 1-line alias: `alias "lsmod=ls -al|awk '{k=0;s=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++){;k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwxst]/)*2^(8-i));};j=4;for(i=4;i<=10;i+=3){;s+=((substr(\$1,i,1)~/[stST]/)*j);j/=2;};if(k){;printf(\"%0o%0o \",s,k);};print;}'"`

Comment: +1 took the idea further to restore working file permissions : 
http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.fi/2013/04/how-to-generate-restore-working-file.html

Comment: Don't use lsmod as an alias.. that's a known posix command for listing kernel mods.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers That is giving me a syntax error from awk

Comment: @EvanLanglois so ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You don't use ls to get a file's permission information.  You use the stat command.  It will give you the numerical values you want.   The "Unix Way" says that you should invent your own script using ls (or 'echo *') and stat and whatever else you like to give the information in the format you desire.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

It is strange that still nobody mentioned the (quote) "*modern replacement for ls*" - an alternative and quite powerful tool [**exa**](https://the.exa.website/).

You can easily achieve the desired output by using `exa` command along with the `-l` (which is equivalent to ls's `-l`) and the `--octal-permissions` options.

---

## Example

Here is a simple example of listing the contents of a user's root directory (`/`) on a macOS machine using *exa* command and the `--octal-permissions` option:

```
exa -lh --octal-permissions /
```

#### Result:

[image]

Notice how besides the nice *colorful* output *exa* can also show the ***headers*** for each column thanks to the `-h` option (long form is `--header`).

Read `man exa` or the official [online documentation](https://the.exa.website/introduction) for more information about how to customize the desired output according to your specific needs.

---

#### The official project page on GitHub:

- https://github.com/ogham/exa

Answer (score 3):

```bash
ls -lvahF --color \
    | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o\t",k);print $5,$6,$7,$8,$NF}' \
    | column -t
```

This does: sort by name, coloring, decimal numbers permissions, and aligns to columns.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795976/can-the-unix-list-command-ls-output-numerical-chmod-permissions#answer-1796009) and the [suggestion to use an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795976/can-the-unix-list-command-ls-output-numerical-chmod-permissions#comment-33754600), I converted it to a function so that passing a directory to list is possible.

```
# ls, with chmod-like permissions and more.
# @param $1 The directory to ls
function lls {
  LLS_PATH=$1

  ls -AHl $LLS_PATH | awk "{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
                            *2^(8-i));if(k)printf(\"%0o \",k);print}"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for some UNIX: `ls: ERROR: Illegal option -- H` then 
`usage: ls -1ACFLRTabcdfgilmnopqrstux -W[sv] [files]` and
`awk: cmd. line:2: fatal: file '/usr/include' is a directory`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the question specifies UNIX, not Linux, use of a `stat` binary is not necessary.  The solution below works on a very old UNIX, though a shell other than `sh` (i.e. `bash`) was necessary.  It is a derivation of [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)'s `perl` `stat` [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246213/22653).  It seems like an alternative worth exploring for conciseness.

```
$ alias lls='llsfn () { while test $# -gt 0; do perl -s -e \
  '\''@fields = stat "$f"; printf "%04o\t", $fields[2] & 07777'\'' \
    -- -f=$1; ls -ld $1; shift; done; unset -f llsf; }; llsfn'
$ lls /tmp /etc/resolv.conf
1777    drwxrwxrwt   7 sys      sys       246272 Nov  5 15:10 /tmp
0644    -rw-r--r--   1 bin      bin           74 Sep 20 23:48 /etc/resolv.conf
```

The alias was developed using information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42466441/856172)

The whole answer is a modified version of a solution in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598868/22653)

Answer (score 0):

After reading MANY answers here, following links provided in comments back to the original UNIX way of doing this, and while wanting to combined what was offered here, as well as the tips and tricks I've already learned, I came up with a new solution.

First off, I used to use this alias, to give me column headers:

```
alias l='echo "Dir Size|Perms|Link Count|Owner|Group|Size|Mod. Time|Name"; ls -haFl --time-style=long-iso --color=always --group-directories-first --format=long'
```

After combining this, with AWK, I first learned I had to alter the awk command, when using the "-s" option for ls, as this shows size in the first column, and you need to then read and parse the second (no longer first) column of data.

The ISSUE I found, was when you then provide input to " l " i.e., you are at a path, and type: l, fine, but what if you type "l" then a directory name?  what if you want to list out everything in a subdirectory?  This wasn't able to happen, as the alias did not handle input.  I was able to handle this with a function.  Then AWk broke, which I was able to handle with a sub-alias.

Combining the two worked perfectly.

Added to my .bashrc file

```
function _bestLS() {
  echo 'MODE|Dir Size|Perms|Link Count|Owner|Group|Size|Mod. Time|Name';
  if [ "$*" == '' ]; then
     alias _awk4ls="awk '{k=0;s=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++){;k+=((substr(\$2,i+2,1)~/[rwxst]/)*2^(8-i));};j=4;for(i=4;i<=10;i+=3){;s+=((substr(\$1,i,1)~/[stST]/)*j);j/=2;};if(k){;printf(\"%0o%0o \",s,k);};print;}'";
     output=`ls -shaFl --time-style=long-iso --color=always -F --group-directories-first --format=long | _awk4ls`;
  else
     output=`ls -shaFl --time-style=long-iso --color=always -F --group-directories-first --format=long $* | _awk4ls`;
  fi
  echo "$output"
}
alias l="_bestLS"
```

Observe (please note, it is a lower case letter L, not a numeric 1, which look the same in this site's font):

```
>>l
```

[image: typing just l]

```
>>l [SOME DIRECTORY]
```

[image: typing l, then a folder name]

P.S. Please excuse my very long (3 line) prompt (PS1)

Answer (score 0):

Could be improved but thats how i roll for now

```
sudo echo "alias ll=\"ls -lha --color=always -F --group-directories-first |awk '{k=0;s=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++){;k+=((substr(\\\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwxst]/)*2^(8-i));};j=4;for(i=4;i<=10;i+=3){;s+=((substr(\\\$1,i,1)~/[stST]/)*j);j/=2;};if(k){;printf(\\\"%0o%0o \\\",s,k);};print;}'\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh

source /etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the first answer very useful but I spent some time with escaping the chars to set it as alias, I end up with setting it as a function in my .bash_aliases file and this is the function:

```
# list directory content and show file permission in number style
function lsn {
    ls -lh --color | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
            *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the top answer at the time and included situations for S and T.

```
ls -l|awk '{if($1~/^.{10}[.]$/){k=0;for(i=0;i<9;i++){c=substr($1,10-i,1);if(!(i%3)){k+=(c~/[stST]/)*2^((i/3)+9)};k+=(c~/[r-x]/)*2^i};printf("%04o ",k)};print}'
```