# Linux List files dfference - "ls" vs "ls /"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ls

Never used Linux before and trying to understand the difference between

```
ls
```

and

```
ls /
```

"ls /" gets all my dir (and more, but not .files - hidden files) as we can see it in [this extensive list of commands](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ls1.html).

What about the `ls`?

Comment: Add '-a' (or '-A') flag to see "hidden" files. It's just a convention to not generally list entries whose name starts with a dot.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ls is standing for listing directories and files under a **directory**.

In your situation, `ls` (**without** a directory argument) is going to list directories and files under the current directory(pwd). The other command, `ls /` is going to list files and directories under the root directory which is `/`.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` alone will print your current directory's contents; you can use ls with arguments to display other information. An example would be `ls -a` where `-a` is the option, and displays listing directories including those starting with a dot (.htaccess for instance). ls has several argument options; short ones begin with a dash (-) like those as mentioned above -a, and there are longer ones too that start with a double dash (--) like `--all` which is the long version of `-a` and does the same thing.

`ls /` is the listing directory (ls) command and `/` is folder structure that ls will act on. In this case, you are invoking a listing of the directory contents on the / folder which is the root directory. An example of the usage of ls and folder structures would be using `ls /home` to display the `/home` directory contents.

To put it all together; you can use ls with an option (-a) and a folder structure like in the example below:

```
ls -a /home
```

I hope this helps!

For an advanced way to view your ls results [please see this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795976/can-the-unix-list-command-ls-output-numerical-chmod-permissions/50686667#50686667)